# Use Picklists in Formulas - Admin Advanced Trailhead Module

Tags: formula, validation-rule, trailhead

Can someone help me with this error?

> There was an unexpected error in your org which is preventing this assessment check from completing: System.DmlException: Insert failed.
>   First exception on row 0; first error:
>   FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, You can only set a case as
>   escalated if it is high priority and not closed: []

**Create a validation rule for escalated cases.**

Create a validation rule formula that does not allow a user to mark a case as escalated unless the priority is set to '`High`', the case was not Closed when Created, and the case isn’t closed.

- The validation rule should be on the Case object.
- The validation rule should be named '`Mark_as_Escalated`'.
- The validation rule should fire if someone tries to set a case as escalated and it is closed, closed when created, or does not have a priority of High.
- The validation rule should display the error message '*You can only set a case as escalated if it is high priority and not closed*' under the Escalated field when triggered.

Add the 'Escalated' field to the Case page layout.

I used this formula to complete the exercise:

```
IF(AND(IsClosed, IsClosedOnCreate, NOT(ISPICKVAL(Priority,"High"))), True, IsEscalated)
```

Comment: Remove `IsClosedOnCreate`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the "if" statement and it's not an AND() but an OR() conditional statement you need to match with your need.

This formula will work :

```
AND(
    IsEscalated,
    OR(
        NOT(ISPICKVAL(Priority, "High")),
        IsClosed,
        IsClosedOnCreate
    )
)
```

Comment: If my answer solve your problem don't forget to accept my answer in order to close your question.

Answer (score 0):

DAVID-IT,

That solution does not work, you can still escalate a closed case

Try this:

```
AND(
IsEscalated = TRUE,
OR(
  TEXT(Status) = 'Closed',
  IsClosedOnCreate = TRUE,
  TEXT(Priority) <> 'High'
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use ISPICKVAL(), you can go with this,

```
(IsEscalated==TRUE)
&& 
(
OR
 (
  ISPICKVAL( Status, 'Closed'), 
  NOT 
  (
   ISPICKVAL( Priority, 'High')
  )
 )
)
```